# Game's split function only works after first time

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Working on recreating Agar.io's split function and it pretty much works but only on the second time... (and afterwards). [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khanfused/8c9h143g/2/). Snippets:

Player.prototype.split():

```
split: function() {
    if (this.radius < 100) return;
    var len = this.cells.length;
    this.radius /= 2;
    this.cells.push(new Player(this.x, this.y, this.radius, this.speed, this.color, this.name, this.id + ' (split)'));
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        this.cells[i].radius /= 2;
        this.cells.push(new Player(this.cells[i].x, this.cells[i].y, this.cells[i].radius, this.cells[i].speed, this.cells[i].color, this.cells[i].name, this.cells[i].id + ' (split)'));
        this.cells[i].accelerate();
        for (var j = 0; j < this.cells[i].cells.length; i++) {
            if (this.cells[i].cells[j] !== undefined) {
                this.cells[i].cells[j].accelerate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Player.prototype.accelerate():

```
accelerate: function() {
    var self = this;
    (function accelerate() {
        self.x += self.accelX;
        self.accelX *= 0.99;
        requestAnimationFrame(accelerate);
     }());
}
```

Comment: Glad you got it sorted! You might delete this question as it relates to a very specific programming glitch that is unlikely to help future SO viewers. :-)

Comment: I was going to, but the system discouraged me because there's an answer  and it could get my account blocked from asking, so...

Comment: I doubt you will get blocked for deleting one question. ;-)

Comment: Well, no, but if you do it too many times, you will, and I've done it twice already in succession, so not gonna risk it. Besides, no harm in leaving it up.

Answer (score 0):

You determine the `len` variable too early.

```
var len = this.cells.length;
...
this.cells.push(new Player(...));
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    ...
}
```

and so the loop is never entered on the first click.

I'm not exactly certain on desired behavior, but you may also be halving the initial radius too early (should be after the push, since it's again halved in the loop?).

Comment: No, moving len down further breaks the code even more. Figured it out though -- I forgot to accelerate the new cell generated by the base.